# How do I chain a set of functions together using promises and q in node.js?

Tags: node.js, q

I have some dynamic data that needs to have work performed on it. The work must happen sequentially. Using the [Q Library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), I'd like to create an array of functions and execute the code sequentially using sequences. I can't seem to quite figure out the syntax to achieve this.

```
const fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "blueberry"]

function makeFruitPie (fruit) {
  return Q.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Do some stuff here
    resolve(fruit+" pie")

    // Error handling here
    reject(new Error(""))
  })
}

const fruitFuncs = new Array(fruits.length)

for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  fruitFuncs[i] = makeFruitPie(fruits[i])
}

// Stole this example from the github docs but can't quite get it right.
i = 0
var result = Q(fruits[i++])
fruitFuncs.forEach((f) => {
  result = result(fruits[i++]).then(f)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these lines

```
for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  fruitFuncs[i] = makeFruitPie(fruits[i])
}
```

you already run the functions and, hence, their processing will begin.

Assuming you want the execution of the functions in sequence, the following would be more appropriate:

```
// construct the pipeline
const start = Q.defer();
let result = start.promise; // we need something to set the pipeline off
fruits.forEach( (fruit) => {
  result = result.then( () => makeFruitPie( fruit ) );
});

// start the pipeline
start.resolve();
```

---

Sidenote: There is a native Promise implementation [supported by almost all environments](https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises). Maybe consider switching from the library backed version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the one that most correctly answers the OP, I see the logic here but I think something is off syntactically. I'm getting 'result.then' is not a function. Back on the node game after years out (last time *we* liked async) so I'm just having trouble getting in the promise mindset. Once again, thanks for the help.

Comment: @SemperFly You're right. I'm just more used to the native implementation nowadays. I corrected the above code (`result = start`-> `result = start.promise`). Please check, if that works.

Comment: That was it. Thanks.

Comment: Follow-up on this, what's the best way to set a 'finally' on this set of Promises?

Comment: @SemperFly If you want a "real" finally  `result.catch( (e) => console.error( e ) ).then( () => /* do something */ )`. If you just want to do something after the pipeline has successfully executed, you can leave out the `.catch()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promise.all

```
Promise.all(fruits.map(fruit=>makeFruitPie(fruit).then(res=> res) )).
then(final_res => console.log(final_res))
```

final_res will give you array of results

Answer (score 0):

you could use `for..of` and do things sequentially. something like this

```
const Q = require("q");

const fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "blueberry"];

function makeFruitPie(fruit) {
  return Q.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Do some stuff here
    resolve(`${fruit} pie`);

    // Error handling here
    reject(new Error(""));
  });
}

for (const fruit of fruits) {
  const result = await makeFruitPie(fruit);
  console.log(result);
}
```

By the way also worth considering native `Promise` insteead of using `q`